# Создал калькулятор все вроде бы правильно но не могу понять в чем ошибка помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#getIMT").click(function() {
  var a = $("#A").val();
  var b = $("#B").val();
  var c = $("#C").val();
  var d = $("#D").val();

  var result = (3.50 * a * b) * 12 + (b * 12) * c;
  $("#imtResult").html("Ваш результат");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div .second class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Среднее кол-во листов в документе</p>
    <input type="number" name="adress" id="A" class="form-control" placeholder="10" required="" />
  </div>
  <div .second class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Среднее кол-во листов в документе</p>
    <input type="number" name="adress" id="B" class="form-control" placeholder="10" required="" />
  </div>

  <div .third class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Средняя цена отправки по городу</p>
    <input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" id="C" required="" placeholder="200" />
  </div>
  <div .fourth class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Средняя цена отправки по стране</p>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="D" class="form-control" placeholder="2" required="" />

  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <button id="getIMT" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Расчитать</button>
  <span id="Result"></span>
  <span id="imtResult"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно что получается на выходе, какое ожидаемое значение?

Comment: `$("#imtResult").html("Ваш результат");` Выводит строку "Ваш результат". Если надо выводить сам результат, замените на`$("#imtResult").html("Ваш результат " + result);`

Comment: Из ошибок сейчас: не видно что вы выводите куда-то результат и переменные `a, b, c, d` содержат в себе строку. Ещё интересно, что за атрибут `.second, .third, .fourth` у вас в тегах

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменные, в которые вы получается `.val()`, содержат строку, а не число.
Да и вы не выводите результат.

```js
$("#getIMT").click(function() {
  var a = Number($("#A").val());
  var b = Number($("#B").val());
  var c = Number($("#C").val());
  var d = Number($("#D").val());

  var result = (3.50 * a * b) * 12 + (b * 12) * c;
  $("#imtResult").html("Ваш результат: "+result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div .second class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Среднее кол-во листов в документе</p>
    <input type="number" name="adress" id="A" class="form-control" placeholder="10" required="" />
  </div>
  <div .second class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Среднее кол-во листов в документе</p>
    <input type="number" name="adress" id="B" class="form-control" placeholder="10" required="" />
  </div>

  <div .third class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Средняя цена отправки по городу</p>
    <input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" id="C" required="" placeholder="200" />
  </div>
  <div .fourth class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <p class="blockquote">Средняя цена отправки по стране</p>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="D" class="form-control" placeholder="2" required="" />

  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <button id="getIMT" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Расчитать</button>
  <span id="Result"></span>
  <span id="imtResult"></span>
</div>
```